# No bootable device boot error

Tags: boot, grub2

My pc is old and slow so decided to delete windows 10 and install ubuntu. i installed ubuntu but after installing there is not any option on boot menu which shows linux. When starting with any option on boot window i take `No bootable devices`  error.

Pc model is : Acer ES1-432-C0Bk

I saw some solutions but never of them worked.
I tried to use grub repair and gave this report https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/c6zt6CgT4N/

I have downloaded Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS as latest version  and used this site for installation. https://wiki.ubuntu-tr.net/index.php?title=Kurulum.

I don`t know much about these things.
Please help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Acer ES1-432-series notebooks used eMMC storage, which requires some extra steps after installing Linux.

*After* installing Ubuntu, you will need to follow these 7 steps:

1. Boot using Ubuntu USB and choose "Try without installing"
2. Launch the application called "Gparted" to get your EFI device name. It will probably look like `/dev/mmcblk0p1`
3. Open the Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
4. Type these commands:
   `sudo mkdir /media/EFI`
   `sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /media/EFI`
   **Important:** Be sure to replace `/dev/mmcblk0p1` with your proper EFI device name if it is different!
5. Create the `/EFI/Linux/` directory:
   `sudo mkdir /media/EFI/EFI/Linux`
6. Copy every file from the `/EFI/ubuntu/` directory to the new one:
   `sudo cp -R /media/EFI/EFI/ubuntu/* /media/EFI/EFI/Linux/`
7. Copy the `BOOTX64.EFI` file from the `BOOT`:
   `sudo cp /media/EFI/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI /media/EFI/EFI/Linux`

There are a lot of steps here but, fortunately, this only needs to be done once.

After you've finished these seven steps, shut down the computer. Once it's off, remove the USB stick and start the computer normally. It should boot right into Ubuntu.

Welcome to Ubuntu

Comment: Thank you so much, it works well.